# Preprocessing textual data into integer indices (like the imdb data set in the tensorFlow text-classification example)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I've been following the TensorFlow text classification tutorial (https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/basic_text_classification), classifying the IMDB reviews.
The IMDB data is a part of the keras distribution, and is downloaded pre-processed. 
I would like to experiment with my own texts. Is there an efficient way to pre-process my own texts into the word->int representation? I have tried using dictionaries, tuples and sorting, but it is very inefficient. I have a feeling there is a more efficient way to do it.

I have scanned the nltk and the keras pre-processing tools, but may have overlooked something there.

Answer (score 1):

For a simple conversion from text sequences to integer sequences, we can use the `keras.preprocessing.text.Tokenizer` module.

> The `Tokenizer` assigns a index ( not zero ) to each word present in the corpus. Using this vocabulary, the texts are tokenized.

Suppose, texts is the list of sentences which you have. Then,

```
tokenizer = keras.preprocessing.text.Tokenizer()
tokenizer.fit_on_texts( texts )
tokenized_messages = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences( texts )
padded_messages = keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences( tokenized_messages , maxlen )
```

Where maxlen is the maximum length to which the tokenized message will be padded ( mostly by adding zeros ).